# Web-part Tile Spacing Issue

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I have a Webpart containing 12 tiles and there in one big row (with arrows to move left and right).

I want them as 3 across and 4 down... This is SharePoint 365/2016 I believe. Sorry not used SP since 2013... so have no idea if this is even possible.

** UPDATE **

When embedding a code I enter:

```
<style>
/*display rows of 3 items*/
.ms-promlink-body {
  width: 480px;
}
/*hide the arrows when you have more items than viewable*/
.ms-promlink-header{
display:none;
}
</style>
```

This in the editor does what I want... when I save it goes.. I check 'EDIT SNIPPET' and get:

```
<style unselectable="on">
</style>
```

Any Ideas on getting this to work?#

*UPDATE*
These sites helped:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26522.sharepoint-2013-promoted-links-change-size-wrap-view-handle-click-event-using-jquery.aspx

http://www.balestra.be/2014/04/easy-way-display-promoted-links-tiles-multiple-rows.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These sites helped:.........

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26522.sharepoint-2013-promoted-links-change-size-wrap-view-handle-click-event-using-jquery.aspx

http://www.balestra.be/2014/04/easy-way-display-promoted-links-tiles-multiple-rows.html